# disable button on or condition

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a Angular-reactive-form, I am using two radio buttons in it.
1)yes, click on yes, open form, which need to be validated properly and button will not be enable until form is validated

2) NO, click on  No, button will be enabled.

So button enable only === (click yes and fill the form) || (click no)

Below is my code, I am making some mistake please let me know

```
    <form  class="flex flex-column flex-row-ns flex-wrap" [formGroup]="basicInfoForm">
      <mat-radio-group class="mt4 inline-flex flex-column">
        <mat-radio-button value="1" (click)="fillInfo = true">Yes, import my information</mat-radio-button>

          <mat-form-field *ngIf="fillInfo" color="primary" class="w-50-ns pr2-ns">
            <mat-label>Social Security Number</mat-label>
            <input matInput placeholder="xxx-xx-xxxx" max="10" formControlName="ssn" required />

          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field *ngIf="fillInfo" class="w-50-ns pr2-ns">
            <mat-label>Phone Number</mat-label>
            <input matInput placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx" required formControlName="phoneNumber" />

          </mat-form-field>
     <mat-radio-button value="2" class="mt4" (change)="fillInfo= false; enableContinue = true;">No thanks, I'll fill out the form myself</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" class="w-100" type="submit"
              [disabled]="basicInfoForm.valid=== false || enableContinue === false">Continue</button>
    </form>
<!-- below button working for one condition only, not accepting or condition-->
 <button mat-flat-button color="primary" class="w-100" (click)="invisible.execute(); next();" type="submit"
          [disabled]="(basicInfoForm.valid=== false )|| (fillInfo=== false)">Continue</button>
```

And ts code related to boolean values is

```
fillInfo: boolean = false;
    basicInfoForm: FormGroup;
    enableContinue:boolean = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sahil Kkr, the main problem is that you have no a Reactive Form. Well We are going to create a ReactiveForm. I inject in constructor the FormBuilder

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
```

And create a the formGroup

```
  basicInfoForm = this.fb.group({
    ssn: ['', Validators.required],
    phoneNumber: ['', Validators.required]
  });
```

We can add a FormControl for manage the "radio" or use a [(ngModel)]

```
  moreInfo=new FormControl('1');
  //or
  moreInfo:number=1
```

the button becomes disabled if basicInfoForm is not valid and moreInfo!=2 -if use a FormControl if moreInfo.value!=2 -

```
 <button mat-flat-button color="primary" class="w-100" type="submit"
              [disabled]="!basicInfoForm.valid && moreInfo!=2">Continue</button>
```

And we can use again moreInfo -or moreInfo.value- to hide the aditional input.

IMPORTANT: if we use [(ngModel)] we must add [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" because the input is inside the "form"

IMPORTANT2: remove the "required" in the input. We are using validators.required when create the formGroup

IMPORTANT3: Really the form is yet invalid

```
<form [formGroup]="basicInfoForm">
    <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="moreInfo" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        <mat-radio-button value="1">
            Yes, import my information
        </mat-radio-button>
         <!--see that simply make not visible using a *ngIf="modeInfo==1"-->
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="moreInfo==1" color="primary" >
            <mat-label>Social Security Number</mat-label>
            <input matInput placeholder="xxx-xx-xxxx" max="10" 
                 formControlName="ssn"  />
        </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field *ngIf="moreInfo==1" >
            <mat-label>Phone Number</mat-label>
            <input matInput placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx"   formControlName="phoneNumber" />
          </mat-form-field>

     <mat-radio-button value="2" >
         No thanks, I'll fill out the form myself</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
    <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="submit"
              [disabled]="!basicInfoForm.valid && moreInfo!=2">
        Continue
    </button>
</form>
```

In the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u9usmk?file=app/radio-overview-example.ts) you has the two options (in the code I remove the class to clarify the code)

***Updated**
If we want that our formGroup was valid or not, we can consider that, in a Reactive Form, if a control is "disabled", Angular not try to validate the form.

There are two problems to make it. We can not use the property [disabled] from the material inputs, we must use the method disable and enable of a FormControl, the second is that all the fields of a FormGroup can not be disabled at time. So we can use the option of using a FormControl to manage the "moreInfo" and add a "fool" property to our FormGroup
In a ngOnInit

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.moreInfo2.valueChanges.subscribe(res => {
      if (res == 1) {
        this.basicInfoForm2.controls.ssn.enable();
        this.basicInfoForm2.controls.phoneNumber.enable();
      }
      else {
        this.basicInfoForm2.controls.ssn.disable();
        this.basicInfoForm2.controls.phoneNumber.disable();

      }
    })
  }
```

And our Form

```
  basicInfoForm2 = this.fb.group({
    ssn: ['', Validators.required],
    phoneNumber: ['', Validators.required],
    fool: ''
  });
```

Comment: I can't select any radio-button by default. Using this approach, yes, radio is coming as by default

Comment: Just, when give value to "moreInfo" write moreInfo = '' and   moreInfo2 = new FormControl('')